# jq returns nothing if nested array is empty

Tags: json, linux, jq

here the array subThings is populated

```
$ echo '[{"thing-1" : "meta1","thing-2" : "meta2","thing-n" : "metan","subThings":[{"subThing-1" : "subMeta1","subThing-2" : "subMeta2","subThing-n" : "subMetan"}]}]' | jq '.'
[
  {
    "subThings": [
      {
        "subThing-n": "subMetan",
        "subThing-2": "subMeta2",
        "subThing-1": "subMeta1"
      }
    ],
    "thing-n": "metan",
    "thing-2": "meta2",
    "thing-1": "meta1"
  }
]
```

you can see here that missing keys are just set to null.

```
$ echo '[{"thing-1" : "meta1","thing-2" : "meta2","thing-n" : "metan","subThings":[{"subThing-1" : "subMeta1","subThing-2" : "subMeta2","subThing-n" : "subMetan"}]}]' |
 jq '[.[] | {"thing-1","thing-5","subThing-2":.subThings[]["subThing-2"],}]'
[
  {
    "subThing-2": "subMeta2",
    "thing-5": null,
    "thing-1": "meta1"
  }
]
```

here the array subThings is empty

```
$ echo '[{"thing-1" : "meta1","thing-2" : "meta2","thing-n" : "metan","subThings":[]}]' | jq '.'
[
  {
    "subThings": [],
    "thing-n": "metan",
    "thing-2": "meta2",
    "thing-1": "meta1"
  }
]
```

instead of nulls for subThing-2 it wipes out all the data.

```
$ echo '[{"thing-1" : "meta1","thing-2" : "meta2","thing-n" : "metan","subThings":[]}]' |
  jq '[.[] | {"thing-1","thing-5","subThing-2":.subThings[]["subThing-2"],}]'
[]
$
```

Why?
Is there a different way to get the data without the empty array wiping everything out?

Comment: 1. Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. It is not clear what "this" is in the question. 2. The expression `.subThings[]["subThing-2"]` is evidently not what you mean.  Perhaps you meant `.subThings["subThing-2"]`

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to generate objects based on the existence of `subThings` objects. That's effectively what `.subThings[]` does in the context of `{"thing-1","thing-5","subThing-2":.subThings[]["subThing-2"]}`.

You need to evaluate the `subThings` separately and replace with `null` if there are none, otherwise it will just simply be `empty` which yields nothing (which is what you're seeing here).

```
map({ "thing-1", "thing-5", "subThing-2": (.subThings[]."subThing-2" // null) })
```

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know if the json I'm getting is bad or if this is a bug in jq. I found this solution using sed to make the array not empty.

```
$ echo '[{"thing-1" : "meta1","thing-2" : "meta2","thing-n" : "metan","subThings":[]}]' | sed 's/\[ *\]/[null]/g' | jq '[.[] | {"thing-1","thing-5","subThing-2":.subThings[]["subThing-2"],}]'
[
  {
    "thing-1": "meta1",
    "thing-5": null,
    "subThing-2": null
  }
]
$
```

Comment: That `[][]` evaluates to the empty stream in jq is a feature, not a bug.